# Makefile with Java

Tags: java, makefile

I realize the make isn't the best tool to be using with Java, but I just wanted to experiment with it. I have this script but I'm not sure why it isn't working:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
SRC_DIR = $(PWD)
.SUFFIXES:  .java .class
.java.class: 
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
$(SRC_DIR)/Fibonacci_Methods.java \
$(SRC_DIR)/Fibonacci_Methods_Test.java \

default: classes

classes: 
    $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

I get this error:

```
/path/to/make_test/Fibonacci_Methods.class 
/path/to/make_test/Fibonacci_Methods_Test.class
make: /path/to/make_test/Fibonacci_Methods.class: No such file or directory
make: *** [classes] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why. My understanding is that this script should define `CLASSES`, which should call `.java.class` target because I'm defining files ending with `.java`. I don't know the purpose of `$(CLASSES:.java=.class)` because I would have thought the compilation be done already before this step.

I have not yet compiled the java code, by the way (so I'm running make with .java files only, if that makes a difference).

Comment: Tabs are significant in Makefiles. Are the lines indented with tabs or spaces?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
classes: 
        $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```

Here you've defined a target with no prerequisites and recipe (which is supposed to be a command that is used to rebuild the target) that consists of a list of .class filenames, so you're getting the error you see because you can't "run" a list of `.class` files.

You want this:

```
classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```

which defines a target `classes` with a set of prerequisites which are the `.class` files you want to build, and no recipe because you don't want to create a target named `classes`.

Comment: Ah thank you. Could you explain: what is the point of this? I'm defining a target `classes` but I don't want to create a target named `classes`?

What is the point of this if I'm already calling the implicit method to compile the .java files?

Comment: That's exactly the reason: you _aren't_ "calling" the implicit rule.  An implicit rule is like a function that takes an argument: just defining the function doesn't call the function.  Make doesn't read the makefile then try to apply every possible rule it can find.  You have to give make a specific target to build.  Then it will use the makefile to try to build _that_ target.  To build that target it will use as many of the explicit and implicit rules as it needs to, and it won't use ones it doesn't need to.

Comment: If you run `make` with no arguments then it will try to build the first explicit target that's defined in the makefile.  If you run `make` with arguments it will try to build each of those arguments as a target.  That's all it will do: if there are no arguments and no explicit targets, make will just say "nothing to do", even if there are 1,000 implicit rules that _could_ be used to create targets.